# How to avoid sass partials generating redundant css code?

Tags: html, css, sass

Let me give you an example of what my problem is.
These are the three partials I have
_colors.scss

```
 */////////_colors.scss/////////*
   $c-base: #063579;
   $c-secondary: #FDB813;
   $c-tertiary: #f2f5f8;
```

_buttons.scss

```
    @import 'colors';
   .btn {
       color: $c-base;
         }
```

_base.scss

```
    @import 'colors';
   body {
      color: $c-base;
        }
```

And the main sass file
styles.scss

```
   */////////styles.scss/////////*
   @import 'colors';
   @import 'buttons';
   @import 'base';
   div{
      background-color:$c-secondary;
      }
```

Now the issue is style.css imported _color.scss for 3 times that results in lot of redundant code in the css.

I use the following gulp task to convert sass to css

```
 gulp.task('sass', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss 
 in app/scss
.pipe(sass())
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({
  stream: true
}))
});
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, since `_colors.scss` only contains variables, importing it multiple times doesn't change the size of the resulting `.css` file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import '_colors' into '_buttons' and '_base'. The fact that you import it first in 'styles.scss' will make it's content available on both of them.

Delete `@import 'colors'` from '_buttons' and '_base'. Your code will still work fine and you will avoid the redundancy.

> _colors.scss

```
$c-base: #063579;
$c-secondary: #FDB813;
$c-tertiary: #f2f5f8;
```

> _buttons.scss

```
.btn {
   color: $c-base;
}
```

> _base.scss

```
body {
    color: $c-base;
}
```

> styles.scss

```
@import 'colors';
@import '_buttons';
@import 'base';
div{
    background-color:$c-secondary;
}
```

After running `compass compile` I obtain:

> styles.css

```
/* line 1, ../../sass/_buttons.scss */
.btn {
    color: #063579;
}

/* line 1, ../../sass/_base.scss */
body {
    color: #063579;
}

/* line 4, ../../sass/styles.scss */
div {
    background-color: #FDB813;
}
```

Comment: When I delete @import 'colors' in _buttons, it throws an error saying Error: Undefined variable: "$c-base".

Comment: Are the `@import` directives `styles.scss` on the same order that you show on the example? I copied the examples that you show and it compiles without errors on my machine.

Comment: It throws an error only when I use gulp task to convert sass to css.

Comment: Have you tried using [Gulp Shopify](https://github.com/zhangyue1208/gulp-shopify-sass)? It will unify all your `@import`s into a single file.

Answer (score 0):

This `coding` issue and `text editor or IDE` suggestion problem. You can choose a good `text editor or IDE` for `SCSS or SASS` writing and read more about `SASS file structure, Variables, @maxin, function etc`.

> Check this IDE and Editor

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) `// It's free and available for all platform. You need to choose approprite plugin for SCSS or SASS.`

[Webstrome](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) `// It's not free but available for all platform. Webstrome is good for write HTML, CSS, SCSS, SASS, LESS, TypeScript, Javascript and more.`

[NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) `// It's free for use and available for all platform.`

**File structure example**

> _color.scss

```
$c-base: #063579;
$c-secondary: #FDB813;
$c-tertiary: #f2f5f8;
```

> _buttons.scss

```
.btn {
    color: $c-base;
}
```

> _base.scss

```
body{
    color: $c-base;
}
```

> style.scss

```
@import "color.scss;"
@import "button.scss;"
@import "base.scss;"
```